# AngularJS multiple parameter filtering with circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, filter, circular-dependency

I'm trying to create an index of shops, showing them grouped by category, so i have two ng-repeat, one for the categories and another for the shops

i have an array for the categories 
(['cat1', 'cat2', ..])

and another with the shops 
([{name: 'shop1', categories: ['cat2', 'cat3']}, ..])

Here's the HTML Code for the repeaters:

```
<div ng-repeat="categoria in categorias | filter:categorySearch:strict">
    <h3>{{categoria}}</h3>
    <hr width="70%" align="left">
    <table style="text-align: center;" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 table table-bordered table-striped" class="tabla_tiendas">
    <tr ng-repeat="tienda in tiendas | filter:{agregada: 'false'} | filterByCategory:categoria:tienda" >
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 tienda-{{tienda.seleccionada}}"><input type="checkbox" ng-change="setPosition(tienda, tienda.seleccionada)" ng-model="tienda.seleccionada" value="{{tienda.id}}"></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 tienda-{{tienda.seleccionada}}">{{tienda.nombre}}</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 tienda-{{tienda.seleccionada}}">{{tienda.categorias}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the Angular Code:

```
app.filter('filterByCategory', function(tienda, categoria){
    return function(tienda, categoria){return _.contains(tienda.categorias, categoria);};
});
```

And finally here are the errors:

```
Error: Circular dependency: 
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:26:368)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:108:41
    at l (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:70:141)
    at Oc.fa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:74:463)
    at k (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:69:505)
    at Oc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:75:29)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:78:241
    at Object.e.$watchCollection (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:88:58)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js:156:40 <!-- ngRepeat: tienda in tiendas | filter:{agregada: 'false'} | filterByCategory:categoria:tienda --> angular.min.js:63
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:63
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:53
l angular.min.js:44
e angular.min.js:39
e angular.min.js:39
e angular.min.js:39
e angular.min.js:39
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:38
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:157
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:89
e.$digest angular.min.js:89
e.$apply angular.min.js:91
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:152
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:23
o angular.min.js:6
c
```

**What is causing the circular dependency and how can i break it? i'm also open to another solution, but it can change the data architecture**

**Edit:**

Here i have a jsFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/truca/HB7LU/1458/
(if i use the filter "filterByCategory" i get the circular dependency, if i use the filter "filterByCategoryScope" i dont get the parameter category, so i can't filter)

Comment: Can you post `tienda` model also?

Comment: tienda is a shop, so it's model is: {name: 'shop1', categories: ['cat2', 'cat3']}

Comment: if you temporarily use the normal `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and use non-minified versions of your script, you will find it easier to identify which variables are which in the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter factory is invalid.

Angular filters are defined in following signature:

```
app.filter('filterName', function(/*optional injectables*/){
  return function(item, param1, param2, ...){
    //some filter-specific calculations...
    return true/false
  }
});
```

and are used in view expressions with following syntax:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filterName:param1:param2"
```

Your filter is improperly defined as:

```
app.filter('filterByCategory', function(tienda, categoria){
    return function(tienda, categoria){
      return _.contains(tienda.categorias, categoria);
    };
});
```

Because of the mix up between the filter factory and the actual filter function, you have instructed Angular to find and inject `tienda` and `categoria` dependencies, but these do not exist as such.

So, the correct filter signature is:

```
myApp.filter('filterByCategory', function(){
    return function(shop, categoria){
        return _.contains(shop.categorias, categoria);
    };
});
```

and usage:

```
ng-repeat="shop in shops | filterByCategory:categoria"
```

Comment: Thak you very much! you helped me a lot guiding me to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved, thank you very much to all of you

Here's the final result into jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/truca/HB7LU/1460/

HTML:
    
        {{category}}
            {{shop.name}}

Filter:

```
myApp.filter('filterByCategory', function () {
    return function (shops, category) {
        return _.filter(shops, function(shop){
            return _.contains(shop.categories, category)
        });
    };
});
```